# Where does the SQL @@VERSION configuration function pulls its data from?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have a vendor product (WennSoft) that attempts to determine the SQL product version by parsing the string returned from the configuration function @@version.  The parsing logic fails for SQL Server 2008 with SP3.  A better approach would have been to use the SERVERPROPTERY("ProductVersion").

We are waiting for them to provide us with a hotfix for this.  I was wondering if it's possible to find out where the value is retrieve from so we can temporarily modify this value to get around the bug.  If I could get @@version to return without the substring "(SP3)" it would give us a temporary workaround while we wait for the hotfix.

Value return from calling @@version:
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3) - 10.0.5500.0 (X64)   Sep 21 2011 22:45:45   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (VM)